# How to schedule a draft note on a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook-pages

When I create a draft note and save it I find that I can only publish and not schedule. Am I missing anything?
Is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One can only schedule a draft post, but not a draft note.**

What you ask for is not (at the moment) supported by Facebook.
Additionally -unfortunately- there is no workaround for that.